# Python array to 1-D Vector

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a pythonic way to convert a structured array to vector?

For example:

I'm trying to convert an array like:

```
[(9,), (1,), (1, 12), (9,), (8,)]
```

to a vector like:

```
[9,1,1,12,9,8]
```

Comment: This doesn't actually look like numpy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
In [15]: import numpy as np

In [16]: x = np.array([(9,), (1,), (1, 12), (9,), (8,)])

In [17]: np.concatenate(x)
Out[17]: array([ 9,  1,  1, 12,  9,  8])
```

Another option is `np.hstack(x)`, but for this purpose, `np.concatenate` is faster:

```
In [14]: x = [tuple(np.random.randint(10, size=np.random.randint(10))) for i in range(10**4)]

In [15]: %timeit np.hstack(x)
10 loops, best of 3: 40.5 ms per loop

In [16]: %timeit np.concatenate(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 13.6 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to use any `numpy`, you can use `sum`:

```
myList = [(9,), (1,), (1, 12), (9,), (8,)]
list(sum(myList, ()))
```

result:

```
[9, 1, 1, 12, 9, 8]
```

Answer (score 8):

Use numpy `.flatten()` method

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
>>> a.flatten()
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a.flatten('F')
array([1, 3, 2, 4])
```

Source: [Scipy.org](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)